# ffmpeg: Attach various codecs to various filtergraph output streams -- How?

Tags: ffmpeg, codec

I have 2 ffmpeg audio outputs mapped out from a filtergraph, thusly:

`-filter_complex "[0:1]..bla-bla-bla..[ac3];[0:2]..bla-bla-bla..[dts]" -map "[dts]" -map "[ac3]"`

Next, I need to encode the 2 audio streams. There has to be a way to specify what codec to use for each stream, eh? Something like this:

`-codec:[dts] dts -codec:[ac3] ac3`

Nope. That provokes "Invalid stream specifier". And all the examples I've found show solely a stream_specifier that refers to an input stream, not to a filtergraph stream.

What I've tried:

`-filter_complex "[0:1]..[ac3];[0:2]..[dts]" -map "[dts]" -map "[ac3]" -codec:dts dts -codec:ac3 ac3`

`-filter_complex "[0:1]..[ac3];[0:2]..[dts]" -map "[dts]" -map "[ac3]" -codec:[dts] dts -codec:[ac3] ac3`

`-filter_complex "[0:1]..[ac3];[0:2]..[dts]" -map "[dts]" -map "[ac3]" -codec:a:dts dts -codec:a:ac3   ac3`

`-filter_complex "[0:1]..[ac3];[0:2]..[dts]" -map "[dts]" -map "[ac3]" -codec:a:[dts] dts -codec:a:[ac3] ac3`

`-filter_complex "[0:1]..[ac3];[0:2]..[dts]" -map "[dts]" -map "[ac3]" -codec:[a:dts] dts -codec:[a:ac3] ac3`

I've also tried all the variations with quotes (e.g. -codec:"[dts]")

All of them provoke "Invalid stream specifier". Are there any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the stream index of the mapped stream among the output streams.
The index is determined by the order of the maps.

In `-map "[dts]" -map "[ac3]" -codec:dts dts -codec:ac3 ac3`,
`[ac3]` is the 2nd mapping so its codec is assigned using `-c:1 ac3` or `-c:a:1 ac3`.

If the maps were `-map 0:v:1 -map "[dts]" -map 0:s:0 -map "[ac3]"`,
then it would be `-c:3 ac3` or `-c:a:1 ac3`

Answer (score 0):

A rather foolproof way is to set the codecs by stream type:
`-c:a CODEC` will set the codec for all audio streams

Adding a positional parameter afterwards let's you specify for different streams without having to count all streams of other types:

`-c:a:0 CODEC` will set the codec for the **first audio** stream

`-c:a:1 CODEC` will set the codec for the **seccond audio** stream

`-c:a:2 CODEC` will set the codec for the **third audio** stream
and so on.

`-c:v:0`  will work similarly for video streams.

Comment: Setting the same codec for all audio streams will not preserve the SOURCE's audio formats (which usually is a mix of ac3 and dts). Better would be '-codec:a copy'.

Comment: In my problem statement, I did not show that I'm speeding up audio by 1.001x via '-atempo=1.001' in the '-filter_complex'. Thus '-codec:a copy' is not possible. The issue here is that the stream mapping scheme (-map) from the filter complex and the scheme at the codec differ. The filter complex utilizes named streams while the codec directive utillizes either input-relative (e.g. 0:i) or type-relative (e.g. a:i) mappings (not named mappings).

Comment: Since 'copy' is one possible parameter for the `-c` (short form of `-codec`) option, that is one possibility.
But without knowing what a user tries to achieve, it is impossible to say what the best choice will be. Sometimes copying won't work or another codec is required. For that reason I added the 'CODEC' as placeholder.
Just take your original question. `-c:a copy` will give you an error there.

Comment: No, the `-c` uses **output** related stream specifiers.
First you -map index_input_file : stream_in_input_file, then you set the codec with -c : stream_in_output_file . You don't need the named specifiers here anymore since you already mapped them to the output. What actually happens inside your filter doesn't matter. Since you always generate a new stream there, you can never just copy it to the output.

Comment: The issue is (was) how to get a named mapping (e.g. -map [dts]) to the right codec (-codec:a:i dts). Yes, the 'i' in the -codec directive is an audio-type, relative output stream number -- or could be an absolute output stream number (-codec:i dts). It turns out that there's no way to route a named mapping ([dts]) to a codec. That, apparently, is a limitation of ffmpeg.