# How is this ffmpeg '-map' documentation? Okay?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, codec

Regarding [ffmpeg: Attach various codecs to various filtergraph output streams -- How?](https://superuser.com/questions/1666874/ffmpeg-attach-various-codecs-to-various-filtergraph-output-streams-how)

Is the following 100% correct?

There are 5 types of '-map's:

1, Input-absolute: index (*i*) all input streams (e.g. -map [0:*i*]),

2, Input-relative: index (*i*) input video streams only (e.g. -map [0:v:*i*]), or input audio streams only (e.g. -map [0:a:*i*]), or input subtitle streams only (e.g. -map [0:s:*i*]),

3, Named maps (e.g. -map "[*name*]") that should be quoted,

4, Output-absolute: index (*i*) all output streams (e.g. -map [:*i*]), and

5, Output-relative: index (*i*) output video streams only (e.g. -map [v:*i*]) or output audio streams only (e.g. -map [a:*i*]) or output subtitle streams only (e.g. -map [s:*i*]),

Filter inputs and unfiltered '-codec's utilize Input-absolute or Input-relative mappings (or are otherwise not mapped to the output).
Filter outputs use Named mappings but '-codec' directives only support Output-absolute or Output-relative mappings, not Named mappings.
'-codec' directives use Output-absolute or Output-relative mappings only.

The difference between Input-absolute (or -relative) mappings and Output-absolute (or -relative) mappings is that, for inputs, the demuxer determines index order while, for outputs, the user determines index order by putting the '-map' directives in sequence.

Streams that are not mapped by at least '-map 0' (i.e. map all of input '0' streams) are dropped (i.e. are not connected to the output).

Comment: Questions shouldn’t be directed towards specific users.

Comment: The reason I did that was to thank Gyan on the same page as my response to him. Next rationale: The reason I made my response to Gyan a new topic is that these comment boxes are so extremely limited. That written, I see that someone (you?) have deleted my thanks to Gyan.

Comment: The best way to thank an answerer on this site is to upvote and/or accept the answer. See the short [tour] to see how to do that.

Comment: @markfilipak - Your “thanks” is unnecessary noise.  We are not a discussion forum.  Questions are not directed towards specific users.

Answer (score 0):

> 1, Input-absolute: index (i) all input streams (e.g. -map [0:i]),

> 2, Input-relative: index (i) input video streams only (e.g. -map [0:v:i]), or input audio streams only (e.g. -map [0:a:i]), or input subtitle streams only (e.g. -map [0:s:i]),

Yes, but without the square brackets.

> 3, Named maps (e.g. -map "[name]") that should be quoted,

Depends on the shell, on Windows (cmd), not needed, but Bash, yes.

> 4, Output-absolute: index (i) all output streams (e.g. -map [:i]), and

> 5, Output-relative: index (i) output video streams only (e.g. -map [v:i]) or output audio streams only (e.g. -map [a:i]) or output subtitle streams only (e.g. -map [s:i]),

The `map` option is meant to specify a mapping from input to output so it expects an input stream spec. Due to how the parser works, a missing file index is treated as input file index 0.

Other per-stream output options such as `-codec` expect an output stream index, absolute (`-codec:4`) or media-type-qualified (`-codec:a:1`).